# Regex returned error in group with match for IPS and hostnames

Tags: python, regex

The script below connects by `SSH` and executes the `CAT` command inside the hosts file and collects all the lines inside it, after that I am trying to separate into two groups of `IPS` and `HOSTNAMES` arrays, removing everything in comment with `#`, but this one **returned me group error when I match regex**

**SCRIPT**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta
import socket
import paramiko
import sys
import re

# create script head
print ('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print ('Initializing UP/DOWN script in: '+str(date.today()))
print ('-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')

Ips = {'192.168.0.254': {'customer' : 'server'}}

output = []
outfinally = []
arrayIPS = []
arrayHostnames = []

for ip in Ips:

    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(hostname=ip, username='root', password="root")
    output.append((ssh.exec_command('cat /opt/hosts.txt')[1]).read().decode())
    ssh.close()

outfinally = [re.split(r'\s*#\s*',line) for line in output[0].splitlines()]

for rows in range(len(outfinally)):
    reg = re.compile(r'^((1?[0-9]{1,2}|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))\.){3}(1?[0-9]{1,2}|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))$')
    arrayIPS.append(reg.match(outfinally[rows][0]).groups())

for rows in range(len(outfinally)):
    reg = re.compile(r'^((?!^((1?[0-9]{1,2}|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))\.){3}(1?[0-9]{1,2}|2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))$).)*$')
    arrayHostnames.append(reg.match(outfinally[rows][0]).groups())

for line in arrayIPS:
    print(line)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "collect.py", line 40, in <module>
    arrayHostnames.append(reg.match(outfinally[rows][0]).groups())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

**hosts.txt**

```
192.168.0.1 #SRVNET
192.168.0.253 #SRVDATA1
192.168.0.252 #SRVDATA2
SRV35 #SRVDATA3
```

Comment: Can you share ```output``` variable for your code? It would be better to the SSH results with ```.decode('ascii')```

Comment: the output variable is the part of the question that is like hosts.txt, and a list of IPS and HOSTNAMES